# Python wx Checkbox in Grid behaving strange

Tags: python, checkbox, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I embedded a checkbox in every row of my wx.Grid.
I used this page as an example: [wx Python wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Change%20wxGrid%20CheckBox%20with%20one%20click)

The problem is, my last checkbox value is never saved and I can't get quite my head around it.
Second problem: Just clicking the Cell and not the checkbox changes the cell value, but not the checkbox. Is there a solution for this? It's possible that the problems are related.

My whole unit can be found [here](http://pastie.org/8963793) (disregard the readout_main references).

I checked that the 1 or 0 value is really there.

Helping me would mean a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Code? what is weird about it? Maybe a screenshot, I'm not sure if a grid (like a spreadsheet grid? no the sizer?) is supposed to have checkboxes in it.

Comment: Code can be found in the unit I linked. The code was provided by the wx python wiki, so it should work normally. \